# Magento - Get Custom Option Value details from Option Value ID

Tags: magento

I have some intriguing questions related to Custom Options of Product:-

1. Is there any difference between Options & Custom Options? This is because I have found two different properties for each Product details, in almost all product-related modules:

   - `options`
   - `custom_options`

   However there is only one class for only the **Product Option**, which tends to take care of the Custom Options. I am seeking clarification on this point.
2. I am trying to fetch the Custom Options of an Ordered Item, including the Custom Option Price and Price Type. The problem is that Magento only stores the Option Value for the corresponding Ordered Item, and not all its details (like Custom Option Price & Price Type).

   So I created an object of this class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Value`, considering only the `drop_down` Custom Option Type. I've provided my code below, but it is still in vain and not fetching the desired results. How can I rectify this code?

Code for point #2:

```
echo "<pre>";
// $collection contains the whole Order Collection
foreach ($collection as $order) {
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $customOptions = $item->getProductOptions();
        
        foreach ($customOptions['options'] as $_eachOption) {
            // Value ID is stored in this field "option_value"
            $objModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option_value')->load($_eachOption['option_value']);

            // This should provide all the details of this particular Option Value as chosen by the Customer when ordering this Product, but unfortunately it doesn't
            print_r($objModel->getData());
            
            /**
             * This gives the output as, without any details on Price and Price Type:-
             * Array
             * {
             *     [option_type_id] => 13014
             *     [option_id] => 4921
             *     [sku] => XBPS22
             *     [sort_order] => 0
             * }
             */

            unset($objModel);
        }
    }
}
echo "</pre>";
```

After doing some checking, I found that the price related to each Option Values are stored in `catalog_product_option_type_price` database table, and the price related to each Options are stored in `catalog_product_option_price` database table. So there must be some way as to how Magento fetches the corresponding Custom Option Value prices.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In this code, I load the product by id, get the option collection, which in my tests only contains the custom options for a product, not attributes or other options, iterate through the options and load the values collection for each option. This demo code should be testable pretty much anywhere as long as you have a product ID.

```
<?php

$productID = $this->getProductId(); //Replace with your method to get your product Id.

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID);
$options = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);

foreach ($options as $option) {
    Mage::log('Name: ' . $option->getDefaultTitle());
    Mage::log('    Type: ' . $option->getType());
    Mage::log('    Class: ' . get_class($option));
    Mage::log('    Price/Type: ' . ($option->getPrice() ? $option->getPrice() : '0.00') . ' / ' . $option->getType());

    if ($option->getType() === 'drop_down') {
        $values = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_option_value')->getValuesCollection($option);
        Mage::log('    Values: (name/price/type)');

        foreach ($values as $value) {
            Mage::log('        ' . $value->getTitle() . ' / ' . $value->getPrice() . ' / ' . $value->getPriceType());
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Example Log Output:

```
2014-02-18T20:15:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): Name: Turtle Color
2014-02-18T20:15:25+00:00 DEBUG (7):     Type: drop_down
2014-02-18T20:15:25+00:00 DEBUG (7):     Class: Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option
2014-02-18T20:15:25+00:00 DEBUG (7):     Price/Type: 0.00 / drop_down
2014-02-18T20:15:25+00:00 DEBUG (7):     Values: (name/price/type)
2014-02-18T20:15:25+00:00 DEBUG (7):         Red / 0.0000 / fixed
2014-02-18T20:15:25+00:00 DEBUG (7):         White / 0.0000 / fixed
2014-02-18T20:15:25+00:00 DEBUG (7):         Blue / 0.0000 / fixed
```

Example available data for `$option Mage::log($option->toArray())`:

note: price and price_type are only available on the option values for drop_down type options.

```
2014-02-18T20:19:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [option_id] => 135
    [product_id] => 80
    [type] => field
    [is_require] => 0
    [sku] =>
    [max_characters] => 25
    [file_extension] =>
    [image_size_x] =>
    [image_size_y] =>
    [sort_order] => 90
    [description] =>
    [default_title] => Turtle Name
    [store_title] =>
    [title] => Turtle Name
    [default_price] => 0.0000
    [default_price_type] => fixed
    [store_price] =>
    [store_price_type] =>
    [price] => 0.0000
    [price_type] => fixed
)
```

Example available data for `$values Mage::log($values->toArray())`:

```
2014-02-18T20:25:21+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [totalRecords] => 2
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [option_type_id] => 1149
                    [option_id] => 229
                    [sku] =>
                    [sort_order] => 10
                    [default_price] => 0.0000
                    [default_price_type] => fixed
                    [store_price] => 0.0000
                    [store_price_type] => fixed
                    [price] => 0.0000
                    [price_type] => fixed
                    [default_title] => 31"
                    [store_title] => 31"
                    [title] => 31"
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [option_type_id] => 1150
                    [option_id] => 229
                    [sku] =>
                    [sort_order] => 20
                    [default_price] => 0.0000
                    [default_price_type] => fixed
                    [store_price] => 0.0000
                    [store_price_type] => fixed
                    [price] => 0.0000
                    [price_type] => fixed
                    [default_title] => 31.5"
                    [store_title] => 31.5"
                    [title] => 31.5"
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Hey, how can i used  '$value->setPrice()' i want to change the options price thanks.

Comment: I see that you're outputting the values from drop-down option types, how about showing the text field values?  I'm trying to gather my data after the item has been added to the cart.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

First load the products from the collection then loop as follows :

```
$product = 100; // product id, you should get first

foreach($product->getOptions() as $options)
{
    $options->getType(); // get option type

    $optionValues = $options->getValues();

    foreach($optionValues as $optVal)
    {
       print_r($optVal->getData());
       // or $optVal->getData('option_id')
    }
}
```

*** Modified ***

```
$prdSku = 125; // sample sku  
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');  
$prdId = $product->getIdBySku($prdSku);  
$product->load($prdId);  

if ($product->getId()) {  
  if ($product->hasCustomOptions()) {  
    foreach ($product->getOptions() as $opt) {  
      $optionType = $opt->getType();  

      if ($optionType == 'drop_down') {  
        $values = $opt->getValues();  

        foreach ($values as $k => $v) {  
          Mage::log("Array Key = $k;");  
          Mage::log("Array Value: $v");  
        }  
      }  
    }  
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this I have already tried, which provided me with blank values for Custom Option Value Price & Price Type. That's why I went on to load a separate instance of Custom Option Value, so that it could provide me with the actual Price & Price Type of that Option Value; but even this way is not providing me with anything. Sorry, but still thanks for trying!

Comment: @Muk I have modified the code, could you please try this as well?

Comment: You saved my time!

Answer (score 3):

A similar question was asked here:

[get selected custom option price for simple product in observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673624/get-selected-custom-option-price-for-simple-product-in-observer)

I gave the following answer there:

---

If you have the option value ID you can also do I direct query to get the option price. I know this is not completely the Magento way and you might have to do some custom calculating (for procent prices for example), but you could do something like this:

```
$optionValueId = 1234; // replace with you option value ID

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$connection = $resource->getConnection('read');

$optionvaluePrice = $connection->fetchRow(
    sprintf('SELECT * FROM %1$s WHERE option_type_id = %2$d', 
        $resource->getTableName('catalog/product_option_type_price'), 
        $optionValueId
    )
);
```

Sadly, Magento doesn't seem to have a model to load a single option price separately.

Answer (score 2):

```
$session= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$getotal = Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
foreach($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item)
{
$options = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->getProductOptionsCollection();
    foreach ($options as $o) 
    { 
        $title = $o->getTitle();
        $values = $o->getValues();

        foreach($values as $v)
        {
        $mydata = $v->getPrice();                           
        }

    }
}
```

You can use this code in order to get price set for custom options for products in shopping cart.